# Is it possible to add a bacula file daemon to Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, backup

I have two Raspberry Pis (an original model B and a Pi 3) and I'd like to be able to back them up to a bacula server.

Is there a file daemon for Raspbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a file daemon for Raspbian?

`apt search bacula` returns a list of things.  While I am not a user, I would guess the one you want is either:

```
apt install bacula-sd
```

Or:

```
apt install bacula-fd
```

Where "sd" seems to stand for "storage daemon" and "fd" for "file daemon".

According to a comment below, you are looking are looking for a meta package that presumably includes the `-fd`:

```
apt install bacula-client
```

There is also a `bacula-server` that might be the corresponding meta package for `-sd`.

Comment: The package necessary is bacula-client, which is a meta package for the necessary client components.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look at is the packages available within Raspbian.

To search for a package use the following command.

`apt-cache search package`

You might have to use variations of the package name or just a few letters if you are unsure of the spelling.

In this case

```
harry:~ $ apt-cache search bacula
bacula - network backup service - metapackage
bacula-client - network backup service - client metapackage
bacula-common - network backup service - common support files
bacula-common-dbg - network backup service - common support files (debugging)
bacula-common-mysql - network backup service - MySQL common files
bacula-common-mysql-dbg - network backup service - MySQL common files (debugging)
bacula-common-pgsql - network backup service - PostgreSQL common files
bacula-common-pgsql-dbg - network backup service - PostgreSQL common files (debugging)
bacula-common-sqlite3 - network backup service - SQLite v3 common files
bacula-common-sqlite3-dbg - network backup service - SQLite v3 common files (debugging)
bacula-console - network backup service - text console
bacula-console-dbg - network backup service - text console (debugging)
bacula-console-qt - network backup service - Bacula Administration Tool
bacula-console-qt-dbg - network backup service - Bacula Administration Tool (debugging)
bacula-director-common - network backup service - Director common files
bacula-director-common-dbg - network backup service - Director common files (debugging)
bacula-director-mysql - network backup service - MySQL storage for Director
bacula-director-mysql-dbg - network backup service - MySQL storage for Director (debugging)
bacula-director-pgsql - network backup service - PostgreSQL storage for Director
bacula-director-pgsql-dbg - network backup service - PostgreSQL storage for Director (debugging)
bacula-director-sqlite3 - network backup service - SQLite 3 storage for Director
bacula-director-sqlite3-dbg - network backup service - SQLite 3 storage for Director (debugging)
bacula-doc - Documentation for Bacula
bacula-fd - network backup service - file daemon
bacula-fd-dbg - network backup service - file daemon (debugging)
bacula-sd - network backup service - storage daemon
bacula-sd-dbg - network backup service - storage daemon (debugging)
bacula-sd-mysql - network backup service - MySQL SD tools
bacula-sd-mysql-dbg - network backup service - MySQL SD tools (debugging)
bacula-sd-pgsql - network backup service - PostgreSQL SD tools
bacula-sd-pgsql-dbg - network backup service - PostgreSQL SD tools (debugging)
bacula-sd-sqlite3 - network backup service - SQLite 3 SD tools
bacula-sd-sqlite3-dbg - network backup service - SQLite 3 SD tools (debugging)
bacula-server - network backup service - server metapackage
bacula-traymonitor - network backup service - tray monitor
bacula-traymonitor-dbg - network backup service - tray monitor (debugging)
harry:~ $
```